# Repeating a command n times

Tags: key-bindings, indentation, commands

For posting code to stackexchange I repeatedly have to do indentation in emacs. I mark a piece of text and then do M-X indent-rigidly four times. Is there an elegant way to do this indentation of text by four blanks in one go?

Comment: Use a prefix argument? `C-u C-x TAB`

Comment: For repeating a <command> <n> times, one could `C-u <n> <comment>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation for `indent-rigidly` says:

> If called from a program, or interactively with prefix ARG, indent all
>   lines starting in the region forward by ARG columns. If called from a
>   program, START and END specify the beginning and end of the text to
>   act on, in place of the region.

To indent by four columns, just pass the prefix argument with `C-u`:

```
C-u C-x TAB
```

Answer (score 5):

Besides the obvious answer of using a prefix arg to specify the number of columns to indent (i.e., `C-4 C-x TAB`), if you use Emacs 24.4 or later then you can simply use arrow keys to repeat indenting, i.e., to incrementally indent. E.g.:

```
C-x TAB <right> <right> <right>...
```

If you use Shift with `<right>` or `<left>` then each repetition indents by a tab stop. Without Shift, each repetition indents by one column.

Comment: This works really well. `C-u` does not work in evil mode. `C-5` will automatically expand to `C-u 5` and even does work with multiple digits when keepin `C` presses. So I can do `C-15 SPC w -` to decrease a window size.

Answer (score 0):

I've written this snippet when Stack Overflow for some reason stopped
recognizing lisp syntax in the code blocks. Might be useful:

```
(defun stackoverflow-block (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((str (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end)))
    (delete-region beg end)
    (insert
     "<!-- language: lang-lisp -->\n\n"
     (mapconcat
      (lambda (x) (format "    %s" x))
      (split-string str "\n")
      "\n"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always used M-[number] to do things. This also works if you just want to type out 80/132 characters to measure the width of your screen or something. There doesn't seem to be a limit on the number of numbers you can put in the prefix.

```
M-80 #
;;Prints out 80 #

M-4 M-x indent-rigidly
;; Indents 4 times

;; Need to separate M-# with C-u if your command is a number
M-80 C-u 0
;; Prints out eighty 0 characters
```